# PDFBox - print encrypted file

Tags: printing, pdfbox

I'm trying to remove protection on some certified PDFs using PDFBox 1.8.0 by printing, following the examples from [here](https://apache.googlesource.com/pdfbox/+/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/printing/Printing.java?autodive=0).

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageable;

public class PDFPrinter {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PDFPrinter.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PrinterException, PrintException {
    LOGGER.info("Running...");
    PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load("C:\\_APPS\\input.pdf");
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PrintService printService = null;
    if (printerJob.printDialog()) {
      printService = printerJob.getPrintService();
      LOGGER.info("Using printer: " + printService.getName());
    }
    printerJob.setPageable(new PDPageable(pdDocument));
    printerJob.print();
    pdDocument.close();
  }

}
```

I'm using the Microsoft Print to PDF printer.
I'm getting a NPE in [PDPageable](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.0/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageable.java/) class @ line 74 saying I ain't got no access permission set on this document:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageable.<init>(PDPageable.java:74)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageable.<init>(PDPageable.java:96)
    at com.util.pdf.decrypt.Main.decryptAndOcr(Main.java:179)
    at com.util.pdf.decrypt.Main.main(Main.java:82)
```

which indeed is null upon checking `pdDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission()`.
So I've tried to manually set some access permissions with no username or password, just with the print privilege:

```
    AccessPermission accessPermission = new AccessPermission();
    accessPermission.setCanPrint(true);
    StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("", "", accessPermission);
    try {
      pdDocument.protect(spp);
    } catch (BadSecurityHandlerException bhe) {
      bhe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But permissions are still null when checking with `pdDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission()`.

Question: How can I set the printing access permission on a PDF?

Note: When I'm printing using Microsoft Print to PDF printer directly from the OS, the certificate is removed from the printed PDF, so the process works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you mentioned is for 2.0. Either use 2.0 (and not 1.8), or in 1.8 do this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("..."));
if (doc.isEncrypted())
{
    doc.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial("password"));
}
```

or use this

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File("..."), null);
```

This should moot the second part of your question. protect() is to be used when you are saving a PDF file.

You should not use 1.8.0. This is several years old. If you must use 1.8, then use the current version, which is 1.8.11.